# Observing "no such element error" while trying to locate an element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

[html code][1]Error :
On trying to locate and element and cliking on it, observing an error as:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Below is the xpath,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navTabs\"]/li[5]/a")).click();
```

Selenium - selenium-java-3.6.0
Java - java-oxygen
Browser - Chrome

I have tried maximize and wait.

Below is the html code for your reference,

`<ul class="nav sidenav-tabs navs-4" id="navTabs" style="display: inline-block; width: 80%;">
            <li class="active" style="width:10%;display:inline-block;"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="setLastTabClickedName(Home)" style="font-size:medium" href="#tab-1">A</a></li>
            <li style="width:10%;display:inline-block;"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="setLastTabClickedName(Chat)" style="font-size:medium" href="#tab-2">D</a></li>
            <li style="width:10%;display:inline-block;"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="setLastTabClickedName(Ivr)" style="font-size:medium" href="#tab-3">B</a></li>
            <li style="width:10%;display:inline-block;"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="setLastTabClickedName(Tmac)" style="font-size:medium" href="#tab-4">C</a></li></ul>`

Comment: Can you please share ur html code?

Comment: I have added the image. Kindly click on link "html code"

Comment: Can you expand all the `<li>` tags and instead of image, paste the `HTML` as text for further analysis?

Comment: But there are only 4 list items, while you're trying to access 5th (indices are 1-based).

Comment: "Previosuy there were 5 items. However it would not work for 5 items" Tried with 4 now. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is only 4 li tag and u are searching for 5th one. so change it to li[4]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navTabs\"]/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Sorry. Previously there were 5 items. Noe changed to 4. However this piece of code would not work. I tried with li[4].Same result. Script terminates with the below error.""""Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 22363
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 27, 2017 2:19:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)

Answer (score 0):

In the starting of your xpath before giveing class you should also give the tag

Like.    //td[@class]

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navTabs\"]/li[4]/a")).click(); -- For example in this xpath, what more is required to be added?

Comment: Add the ul tag in the starting 
//ul[@id=......

As the id you are using is of the ul tag